# Is there any way to replace 0 value in array using regular expression?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to replace 0 value in array using `regular expression` in Jquery?

My Array is

```
var arr=[11,12,0,45,55,88,0,0,0];
```

I want to replace this `'0'` with `Null`

Comment: `Regular expression` is actually for manipulating the strings.!

Comment: That's not an array, it's a string, if it where an array you'd do `arr = arr.map(function(x) { return x === 0 ? null : x });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it with replace.

```
With String value you do like this

arr.replace(/0/g, 'null')
```

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChKB7/)

```
With arr value check this
```

[Array Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChKB7/2/)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is way longer than the others but I think it's the only that takes the string, and returns a proper array with the zeroes replaced:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/yLytR/1/

```
var replaceZeroesAndConvertToArray = function( st ) {
    st = st.replace('[','').replace(']','');
    st = st.split(',');
    st[st.indexOf('0')] = null;
    for (var i = 0, l = st.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (st[i] != null) {
            st[i] = parseInt(st[i]);   
        }
    }
    return st;
}
```